Getting Error on Firebase login | Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
I have just created a React Project , and followed the steps given by firebase to deploy this app to firebase. While doing firebase login I'm getting this error.
I tried adding URI in OAuth 2.0 Client IDs , but didn't get any results.




The error message you are encountering "redirect_uri_mismatch" indicates configuration issue with firebase authentication and google OAuth2. It occurs when the redirect URI used during the login process doesn't match the ones registered for your firebase project. Check OAuth Client IDs and fix redirect URIs.
It would be better to provide more information of your issue and code snippet.

I have provided more info , can you check I'm stuck for a while on this
